# CSS to style OrderedList numbers in <OL> tag

Tags: html, css

I want to left-align an ordered list and also change the style of the list numbers in that ordered list. Here is my CSS:

```
.tour-features ol {
    text-align:left;
}

.tour-features ol > li:before {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: impact, sans-serif;    
}
```

Here is how I'm calling it in the HTML

```
<ol class="tour-features">
    <li>Check out our suggested Egypt Tours.</li>
    <li>Contact us for a free quote today.</li>
    <li>Let us customize any tour just for you.</li>
</ol>
```

And it's not working. [Here's my Codepen showing the result](http://codepen.io/webidextrous/pen/yVaaON). Nothing changes. No left-alignment of the list and no change to the default look of the numbers in the ordered list.

I'm sure it's something simple. I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had your css as `.tour-features ol` instead of `ol.tour-features` and you have to play with the `padding-left` as below.

```css
/*ol.tour-features {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

ol.tour-features > li {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: impact, sans-serif;    
}*/

ol.tour-features {
 counter-reset:li; /* Initiate a counter */
 margin-left:0; /* Remove the default left margin */
 padding-left:0; /* Remove the default left padding */
}
ol.tour-features > li {
 position:relative; /* Create a positioning context */
 margin:0 0 6px 2em; /* Give each list item a left margin to make room for the numbers */
 padding:4px 8px; /* Add some spacing around the content */
 list-style:none; /* Disable the normal item numbering */
 border-top:2px solid #666;
 background:#f6f6f6;
}
ol.tour-features > li:before {
 content:counter(li); /* Use the counter as content */
 counter-increment:li; /* Increment the counter by 1 */
 /* Position and style the number */
 position:absolute;
 top:-2px;
 left:-2em;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 width:2em;
 /* Some space between the number and the content in browsers that support
    generated content but not positioning it (Camino 2 is one example) */
 margin-right:8px;
 padding:4px;
 border-top:2px solid #666;
 color:#fff;
 background:#666;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
 text-align:center;
}
li ol,
li ul {margin-top:6px;}
ol ol li:last-child {margin-bottom:0;}
```

```html
<ol class="tour-features">
    <li>Check out our suggested Egypt Tours.</li>
    <li>Contact us for a free quote today.</li>
    <li>Let us customize any tour just for you.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I change just the numbers to the impact font at 24px in size while leaving the words next to them unchanged? Going by [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/) I had put the :before pseudoelement in thinking that would change just the numbers.

Comment: I have updated the style. You can customize it as you want :-)